# Where to find the latest wrapfs source code

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, vfs

I am planning to self study wrapfs, I downloaded the source from Florida state universities wrapfs page.

However, it seems an older version, since it uses big kernel smp locking mechanisms and is probably designed for <=2.6 kernel .

It would be helpful if someone pointed of any latest wrapfs source code designed for >3.x.x kernel.

Thanks

Comment: Probably this https://github.com/mayli/wrapfs-latest ,,, for kernel 3.xx ... Easy to find : Use Google https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=wrapfs+git

Comment: And here we have patches, also for 4.xx :  "wrapfs-v4.3-586-gd597e83.diff.gz"  http://download.filesystems.org/wrapfs/patches/ ,,, Ref. http://wrapfs.filesystems.org/ ,,, from the same ~4,000 hits with Google, wrapfs git

Answer (score 1):

It seems the official repository is here:

http://git.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/?p=wrapfs-latest.git;a=summary
(Working, just checked)